# How to append a string to a string[], assignment doesn't work

Tags: c#, string

```
string[] string1;
string string2;
string1 = string2;
```

This always gives me an error saying that I can't convert `string` into `string[]`. How would I be able to "append" `string2` into `string1`? I have to add more than one `string` into it so if there is any way to be able to add more than one `string` into `string1` I would very much appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate them? Are you trying to add a string to an array of strings?

Comment: Please use a subject line that will be more useful to future visitors to the site.

Comment: I think you'd actually get more help if you'd describe what you're trying to accomplish rather than talking about the specific error you're seeing.  As @Josh notes, it's not clear what problem you are actually trying to solve and the answer I would give would depend greatly on that.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, but it looks as if I already got my answer. I'm trying to use an array of strings to add to a `choices` which is used in Microsoft's Speech SDK. @RaymondChen Sorry, I will do better next to add a subject line. I'm pretty new to this forum so I'm still learning the correct way to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a single string into a whole array of `string`.

This is not possible.

You need to either select which element of the array to use.

Better yet, use a `List<string>` instead of an array - it is a better structure as it is not constrained by its initial size.

```
List<string> string1 = new List<string>();
string string2;
string1.Add(string2); // Will add a null
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been a big hassle for me. Hopefully now I can finally finish my project!

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to first use a list and store all the strings in there. Then, as a last step, convert the list into an array.
This is especially suitable, if you *do not know the number of strings you want to store* in the array before you start storing them.
However, this has some **performance implications** and it **might not be the best feasible solution** depending on what you are actually trying to do.

```
string string2 = "HelloWorld";
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add(string2);
// repeat for all objects

string[] string1 = list.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an array of strings of size two:

```
string[] string1= new string[2];
string string2 = "test"; //You must also assign something to your string before using it.
string1[0] = string2;
```

To concatenate two strings:

```
string string3 = "third";
string string4 = "fourth";
string string5 = string3 + string4; //string5 is now "thirdfourth"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to `Array` is not trivial operation... If you just need to have collection of strings that  can grow use `List<string>` and don't forget to create object:

```
List<string> string1 = new List<string>();
string string2 = "test";
string1.Add(string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *need* to work with string[] and append elements, do it like this:

```
        string2 = string1 .Concat(new[] {
            stringa, stringb,stringc,stringd....
        }).ToArray();
```

or for a single:

```
        string2 = string1.Concat(new[]{ string2 }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`string1` is an array of strings. `string2` is a string.

First create an array of the appropriate size

```
string1 = new string[10];
```

Then add strings to this array by specifying an index;

```
string1[0] = string2;
string1[1] = "Hello";
string1[2] = "World";
```

and so on. You can do this until `string[9]` in this example, since the indexes range from `0` to the size of the array minus 1.

If you don't know the size of the array in advance, you can use a `List<string>` instead. Lists grow automatically

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add(string2);
list.Add("Hello");
list.Add("World");

foreach (string s in list) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```